# Is it possible to replace a string in an executable which belongs to another user without affecting the file permissions?

Tags: linux, string, bash, permissions, elevated-privileges

I have a simple executable file which belongs to another user. At some point you have a system("ls /path/file") command, and the `/path/file` has the same owner as the executable and can be read only by it. I tried changing the `ls` command with `sed` so that i can see the content of the file, but it affects the ownership. Is there any way to change a string in the executable and keep the ownership?

Comment: I think you are confused about something: the ownership will only be changed when YOU run the executable, not when THEY run the executable. Furthermore, you've tagged your question as "elevated privileges" but haven't explained where the elevated privileges are coming from, so either you're missing something in your question, or you're incorrect in thinking that the file can only be read by the other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing ownership change is most likely that your editor doesn't modify the file. Instead, it creates a new file (necessarily owned by you) that replaces the existing one.

GNU `sed -i` uses this model, so editing a file will it will cause ownership to change:

```
$ ls -l foo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bob    ourgroup   26 Nov  5 18:10 foo

$ sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' foo
(no output)

$ ls -l foo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice  ourgroup   26 Nov  5 18:10 foo
```

To preserve ownership, simply use an editor that will overwrite instead of replace. `nano` and `vim` are interactive editors that do this, while `ed` is a scriptable one.

Note that if the file has the suid u+s bit set, the file can not be modified by anyone else while retaining this permission.